# Salesforce SSO SAML Validation

Tags: salesforce, single-sign-on

I am creating a SAML assertion for the Salesforce SSO. I used OPEN SAML for creating the assertion.
I am getting the following error. Please tell the root cause of this issue and how to resolve this ASAP.

Thanks in Advance.

Results

```
Last recorded SAML login failure:  2014-08-29T08:33:55.713Z
Unexpected Exceptions
  Ok
1. Validating the Status
  Ok
2. Looking for an Authentication Statement
  Ok
3. Looking for a Conditions statement
  Ok
4. Checking that the timestamps in the assertion are valid
  Ok
5. Checking that the Attribute namespace matches, if provided
  Not Provided
6. Miscellaneous format confirmations
  Ok
7. Confirming Issuer matches
  Ok
8. Confirming a Subject Confirmation was provided and contains valid timestamps
  Ok
9. Checking that the Audience matches, if provided
  Ok
10. Checking the Recipient
  Ok
11. Validating the Signature
  Is the response signed? false
  Is the assertion signed? true
  The reference in the assertion signature is valid
  Signature or certificate problems
  The signature in the assertion is not valid
  Is the correct certificate supplied in the keyinfo? false
12. Checking that the Site URL Attribute contains a valid site url, if provided
  Not Provided
13. Looking for portal and organization id, if provided
  Ok
14. Checking if session security level is valid, if provided
  Ok
```

Comment: yes, I will try my best to answer a question without code and errors ASAP

Comment: just to add that below this Result i am getting this message too. 

Subject: user@user.com(some user mail id)
Unable to map the subject to a Salesforce.com user
AssertionId: _284dd858-fd6e-4959-8789-2d7f06b4a0d5

Comment: this issue got sorted out?

Answer (score 0):

Well -- on the surface it looks like you signed your Assertion with one key but it's not the one you provided to SFDC or you included the wrong cert in your keyinfo --

```
Signature or certificate problems
The signature in the assertion is not valid
Is the correct certificate supplied in the keyinfo? false
```

Just a guess at this point. Not enough info provided to really give you a solid answer.